# Can we say we are safe from XSS attacks if we remove all script and java words from input

Tags: c#, asp.net, xss, sanitization

I am using asp.net htmleditorextender and unfortunately there is no working XSS sanitizer right now. So for as quick solution i am replacing all of the script and java words from user input as below

```
    var regex = new Regex("script", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    srSendText = regex.Replace(srSendText, "");

    regex = new Regex("java", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    srSendText = regex.Replace(srSendText, "");
```

Can i assume that i am safe from XSS attacks ?

Actually i am using htmlagilitypack anti xss sanitizer but it is not even removing script tags so totally useless

Comment: [How To: Prevent Cross-Site Scripting in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649310.aspx)

Comment: Just making sure you properly escape the input before rendering it as HTML (or escaping it when it comes in) is how you'd usually prevent XSS

Comment: Have you tried attacking it yourself?

Comment: One of the reasons I love razor: if you make a mistake, you will usually end up double-encoding data, rather than opening up an XSS hole. One of these two things is easily spotted and risk-free; the other is subtle and really dangerous...

Comment: Some other potential vulnerabilities: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5779875/is-worrying-about-xss-csrf-sql-injection-cookie-stealing-enough-to-cover-web-se

Comment: @jbabey can you explain more. what do you mean by escape the input =?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't.

An attacker can easily circumvent such a check by for example encoding `script` as `s&#99;ript`.

Making the code safe from XSS attacks is done by making sure that any content that can come from a user is never put in the page without proper encoding, to make sure that any code in the text is not executed at all.

Comment: i see. so i need to first decode replace then encode and save :)

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: No. Replacing a few keywords doesn't protect you. You should encode the text when you put it in the page so that and markup is not executed at all, instead of trying to remove dangerous keywords so that the markup can be executed.

Comment: how do i do that ? can you show example ? aren't i supposed to decode and display to the user ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: That depends on what application type you are using. For example in a web form application you use `<%= Server.HtmlEncode(text) %>` to encode the output.

Comment: i suppose encoded text is decoded by browser but not executed as script right ?

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG: Yes. Any HTML tags would be displayed on the page as text instead of parsed into elements.

Answer (score 1):

Custom XSS prevention is usually a no no in my opinion as you should always use a library.  However stripping `script` and `java` is not enough, anything that's passed up to the server should use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` which will encode any input from the user.

Also ensure that `validateRequest="true"` is set in the config file.

Other dangerous tags may include:

- applet
- body
- embed
- frame
- script
- frameset
- html
- iframe
- img
- style
- layer
- link
- ilayer
- meta
- object

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649310.aspx

Comment: @MonsterMMORPG you can use AntiXSS - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa973814.aspx